# How does Catholic doctrine differ from LDS doctrine concerning God the Father?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, lds

In a [related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54757/mormonism-doctrine-of-a-flesh-bones-god), it was asked,

> How do Mormons explain the apparent contradiction to their belief that God the Father has a body of flesh and bones found in the paralleled scriptures below;
>
> > John 4:24 God is a Spirit...
> >
> > Luke 24: ... a spirit does not have flesh and bones...

to which one inidividual answered,

> Good question.
>
> God is a spirit as we are spirits—each human has a spirit residing within a mortal body. Likewise, Mormons believe God is a spirit residing within a perfected, glorified, and immortal body.
>
> From lds.org:
>
> > The Greek text of John 4:24 contains no article before the word spirit. Thus, the Greek phrase can also be understood to mean “God is spirit,” or “God is spiritual.” The Apostle John also wrote that “God is light” (1 John 1:5) and “God is love” (1 John 4:8), but these statements do not mean that God is only light, or that God is love and nothing else. Neither do we understand the statement that “man is spirit” (D&C 93:33) to mean that man is only spirit and nothing else. In the same sense, John 4:24 does not mean that God is only spirit. From latter-day revelation, we know that “the Father has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man’s; the Son also; but the Holy Ghost has not a body of flesh and bones, but is a personage of Spirit” (D&C 130:22).
> >
> > In the context of the Savior’s teachings about true worship, the statement in John 4:24 can be seen as commentary more about the nature of worship than the nature of God. Since God is a spiritual being, people must worship Him “in spirit and in truth” (John 4:24), not merely through outward rituals performed at certain locations (see John 4:20–21).
> >     [Introduction and Timeline for John 2–4](https://www.lds.org/manual/new-testament-student-manual/introduction-to-the-gospel-according-to-st-john/chapter-22-john-2-4?lang=eng)

Is Catholic doctrine in agreement with the individual’s answer (i.e., LDS doctrine)? If not, in what way does the aforementioned LDS doctrine (per LDS.org) differ from Catholic doctrine?

Comment: [Possibly related question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/33246/24204)

Answer (score 3):

Catholic doctrine does not agree with LDS doctrine

[CCC 370](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p1s2c1p6.htm#370)

> **In no way is God in man's image. He is neither man nor woman. God is pure spirit** in which there is no place for the difference between the sexes. But the respective "perfections" of man and woman reflect something of the infinite perfection of God: those of a mother and those of a father and husband.

LDS doctrine on [God](https://www.lds.org/topics/god-the-father?lang=eng&old=true)

> God the Father is the Supreme Being in whom we believe and whom we worship. He is the ultimate Creator, Ruler, and Preserver of all things. He is perfect, has all power, and knows all things. He “**has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man's**” (D&C 130:22).